# Can I create field with type JunctionIdList?

Tags: custom-field, metadata, documentation

Is it possible to create a new field with the type JunctionIdList?

It would be very useful but it's not available under the field type options in the new field wizard.
[image: field types available via UI]

In the documentation there's a field type called JunctionIdList. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/field_types.htm

Is this field type createable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To create a many-to-many relationship, your only option is to create a junction object that looks up to the two objects you wish to relate.

That field type is only available to relate activities to a select few standard objects. See [JunctionIdList Fields on Event and Task Objects](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer15/release-notes/rn_sales_activities.htm). Note where it says:

> Create many-to-many relationships on the Event or Task object with contacts, leads, or users in the API. For usage details see, Task Usage or Event Usage